# Display form errors in react app using redux saga and redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I am trying to figure out how to display an error in my login redux form using redux saga. I am able to make the request, but I need to somehow show a message to the user if the response is 403 - forbidden.

**System:**

- react 16.0.0
- redux 3.7.2
- redux-form 7.1.2
- redux-saga 0.16.0

**login-form.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {submit} from '../../actions';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.submit(values);
  }

  renderField(field, label) {
    // ommited
  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit, error} = this.props;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>

        {error ? error : ''}

        <Field
          name="email"
          label="Email*"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          name="password"
          label="Heslo*"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Heslo"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Button color="primary">Login</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm'
})(
  connect(null, {submit})(Login)
);
```

**actions.js:**

```
export const submit = function(data) {
  console.log("Action:", data);
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_SUBMIT',
    data: data
  };
};
```

**sagas.js:**

```
import {takeEvery, fork, call, put} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import {SubmissionError} from 'redux-form';

async function submitToServer(data) {
  try {
    let response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', data);
    yield put({type: 'REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL', payload: result.data})
  } catch(error) {
    throw new SubmissionError({_error: "Some error message"});
  }
}

function* callSubmit(action) {
  yield call(submitToServer, action.data);
}

function* submitSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('REQUEST_SUBMIT', callSubmit);
}

export default function* root() {
  yield [
    fork(submitSaga)
  ];
}
```

Everything works as expected, but I cannot figure out how to actually make the login form to display the error message thrown in my saga. Should I be actually throwing `SubmissionError` in my saga or is there some better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually where the redux global state comes into play.

Your `actions.js` file shows one action type: `REQUEST_SUBMIT`. I assume there's also `REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL` in there, since you're dispatching that in your saga when the api call suceeds.

With async stuff like http requests, you'll probably have 3 actions for the whole request/response/error flow.

When you catch that exception in your saga, you'd dispatch this 3rd `REQUEST_FAILED` action, with the error message as the action payload.

`yield put({ type: 'REQUEST_FAILED, payload: error });`

Then in your `reducers.js`, you'd have your reducer listen for this action type, and then update the state with your error message.

Finally, in your component, you'd access this error message from your state by defining a `mapStateToProps` function, which you pass to your `connect` call.
This part is pretty much the stuff in the getting-started docs for the react-redux lib.

Comment: Thanks but that's not really what I am asking. Nothing of what you wrote won't add an error to the redux form. I know I could add any error to my own state outside of redux form, but what I want to do is actually populate redux form error fields if the request fails.

Answer (score 1):

In the middleware before submitting the request call

`yield put(startSubmit(formId))`

In the error handling block call e.g.

`yield put(stopSubmit(formId, { _error: 'Connection error' }))`

If no error occurs you can simply call

`yield put(stopSubmit(formId))`

to indicate that the form has been successfully submitted.

`startSubmit` and `stopSubmit` functions can be imported from 'redux-form'

The redux form component prop `error` will be the string 'Connection error'.

Answer (score 0):

Redux-form wants the submit handler to return a promise, and will display errors from that being rejected.

The easiest way is to use some glue code like: https://github.com/mhssmnn/redux-form-saga or
https://github.com/afitiskin/redux-saga-routines

It's quite simple glue code:

- Return a promise
- Dispatch an action with the resolve/reject handlers on it
- Use a saga to fire form-specific actions from that
- From your saga, dispatch form-specific success/failure actions
- The glue calls resolve/reject on the promise depending on which gets called

Alternatively, you could manually set the field errors with the redux-form action creators: https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this exact same issue. When you throw a `SubmissionError` with a message keyed to `_error`, the message populates in the `error` prop of the form. It does not populate in the `meta.error` prop of the form field, which is where my validation errors populate.

I am using a variation of the "renderField" component used in the following example: https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/syncvalidation/. I updated this component like so:

1. Within the form, pass the error prop to the `<Field />` component.
   I named the prop "ajaxSubmitError" to differentiate it from validation errors.
2. In the "renderField" component, add a conditional check for ajaxSubmitError (or whatever you decide to name the prop) when rendering errors.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

It just occurred to me that my use case is rather specific, so I will give some context around my answer. I'm doing a "wizard" form, which means that I'm only displaying one field at a time. In addition to this, I'm posting data to the backend API on each "step" of the form, as opposed to making one POST request at the end of the form.This is I want the submit error to be displayed in the context of a specific  field (there is only one field showing at a time).

Assuming you are not doing a wizard form, you probably just want to add a component to your form that renders conditionally if there is an error prop on the form.